# plotting 3d points: z-axis is squashed

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I am plotting 3D points and it occurs to me that Mathematica doesn't have an easy way to specify my points to be plotted in a uniformly scaled cartesian space.

For example I plotted

```
Show[ListPointPlot3D[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}], AspectRatio -> Automatic,  PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

And I get this:

[image: 0,0,0 and 1,2,3]

I would like to be looking at a box with the dimensions 1,2,3, not something like 3,3,1. The AspectRatio and PlotRange do not help, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the option `BoxRatios -> Automatic`.

```
ListPointPlot3D[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. How do I know? `ListPointPlot3D[{{0, -1, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}, BoxRatios -> Automatic]` Thanks again.